# How has the Grandmaster title evolved?

Tags: rating, fide, grandmaster

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandmaster_%28chess%29) is a good starting point, but I'm also interested in how the specific regulations have changed over the years.

Currently, 3 norms must be achieved<sup>1</sup> in tournaments that adhere to specific guidelines including foreign players, titled players, and a certain performance rating must be attained.

What was the origin of the current rules, and what were the earlier rules?

---

1. Usually...  there are exceptions to this however.

Comment: I answered but deleted it - I expressed my opinions, only to find they were mirrored in the link you posted.  The link's pretty much a full answer.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I thought your answer was a good summary and added information, you didn't need to delete it!

Comment: Ok, I put it back; SO retains deleted posts for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way it is evolving is with the informal 'super-GM' title.  At one time, there weren't many GMs.  Being a GM was being in an elite club.  Now there are a lot of GMs and the differences in their strengths are beginning to show.  (I'm not talking about a GM's performance degrading due to age...)

From the wiki linked below:

> In 1972 there were only 88 GMs with 33 representing the USSR. The
>   current FIDE ratings list includes over 1000 grandmasters.

Perhaps 20 years ago, a GM rated 2600 was a 'super GM'.  Now 2700 could well be that mark, with some GMs peaking at 2850 or so.

Also from the article:

> December 2008 saw a record number of GMs (1,192) and IMs (2,916)
>   causing some FIDE officials to suggest that FIDE should consider an
>   "elite grandmaster" title.[17] The unofficial title, "Super
>   Grandmaster", is often used by players to refer to those with a 2700+
>   rating to distinguish the most serious world champion contenders.

[Read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandmaster_%28chess%29).  This article also includes a synopsis of how GM and IM norms are earned, including rules changes by year.  It's very interesting.